# Excel VBA Find() with dates issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of dates in column `B` like `06/03/2017` formatted in a custom `dd-mmm` formatting giving me `06-Mar` output.

If I manually do Find/Replace and search for `06-Mar` and select `Look In: Values`, it finds it no problem, however doing the same via VBA isn't working.

```
Dim Source as Worksheet, Dest as Worksheet
Dim mDate as String, copyRow as Integer

Set Dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Updates")
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Updates")
mDate = Dest.Range("B2").Text
copyRow = Source.Range("B:B").Find(What:=mDate, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

I have tried getting `mDate` as a value and searching in formulas and values, but nothing seems to work.

The line debugs on `copyRow = Source.......` however if I open the Find/Replace window manually at this point, it fills out the search bar with "06-Mar", and finds the value in column `B` no issues.

If I replace `mDate` with string I know is there, for example `Find(What:="W/C".....` it returns `copyRow` as 1 (because its the header of that column).

Any suggestions what I am missing here?

**EDIT**

To cover a few of the comments below:

Yes the sheets are named the same, just in different workbooks (master file to pull data from multiple identical sources)

In terms of the formatting, I get the search criteria from a date with a true value of `06/03/2017` formatted as `dd-mmm`, searching in a range of data as true dates `06/03/2017` formatted also as `dd-mmm`.

Comment: What is your goal?  Your example is working for me.  I think maybe you haven't explained your issue completely.  Do you mean to be looking in `xlFormula`?

Comment: are realy your source and destination sheets the same? mDate is realy in Dest worksheet or is it an error?

Comment: @D.O. - I suspect different workbooks with different worksheets named the same.

Comment: For me it is working only if: `Dim mDate As Date` and `LookIn:=xlFormulas`

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the variable mDate the same format of your date :

```
copyRow = Source.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Format(mDate, "dd-mmm"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```